# BQL in PXSelector to filter by a Starts With

Tags: acumatica

I've got a field in my DAC where I want to put a selector that looks up the SalesPersons.  I know how to do this:

```
        [PXSelector(typeof(SalesPerson.salesPersonCD)
               ,typeof(SalesPerson.salesPersonCD)
               ,typeof(SalesPerson.descr))]
```

My problem is that I want to filter this selector based on the first three characters of the SalesPerson CD, i.e., StartsWith "SSR" or something similar.  I know you can use BQL in a selector using the Search<> command, and I know how to set up a constant class, but I'm not sure of the syntax to filter by beginning characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short of creating a custom BQL operator, you can achieve "Starts with" by using the LIKE operator, with the % wildcard at the end. The BQL field you're filtering on could be a DAC property with custom code in the get accessor, which takes your user-entered field and adds the wildcard character at the end, like that:

```
        public abstract class myFieldWildcard : PX.Data.IBqlField { };
        [PXString(30, IsUnicode = true)]
        public virtual String MyFieldWildcard
        {
            [PXDependsOnFields(typeof(myField)]
            get
            {
                return MyField + PXDatabase.Provider.SqlDialect.WildcardAnything;
            }
        }
```

You'll then be able to use that field as part of your `PXSelector` attribute:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<SomeTable.someField, Where<SomeTable.someField,Like<Current<MyFilter.myFieldWildcard>>>>))]
```

Comment: Thanks much, guys!   ;D